# Find the occurrences (count) of all elements at all positions in an array in Postgres?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

How can we find the occurrence count to position mapping for elements in an array type in postgres ?

For example:

```
["A", "B", "C", "D"]
["A", "B", "C", "D"]
["A", "B", "D", "C"]
["A", "D", "C", "B"]
```

Should yield

| Element | Position | Occurrences |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 4 |
| A | 2 | 0 |
| A | 3 | 0 |
| A | 4 | 0 |
| B | 1 | 0 |
| B | 2 | 3 |
| B | 3 | 0 |
| B | 4 | 1 |
| C | 1 | 0 |
| C | 2 | 0 |
| C | 3 | 3 |
| C | 4 | 1 |
| D | 1 | 0 |
| D | 2 | 1 |
| D | 3 | 1 |
| D | 4 | 2 |

I know about that `array_position` can get the position (1-based) but I am stumped as to how to achieve what I want ?

**SQL Query:**

```
create table test (id integer, priorities varchar(100)[]);
insert into test (id, priorities) values (1, '{"A","B","C","D"}');
insert into test (id, priorities) values (2, '{"A","B","C","D"}');
insert into test (id, priorities) values (3, '{"A","D","C","B"}');
insert into test (id, priorities) values (4, '{"A","C","B","D"}');
```

**Edit #1**: I think I can somehow combine `unnest with ordinality` and `group by` to achieve this.

Comment: That looks more like a JSON array, not a native array. Which data type is the column exactly (it makes a difference for the functions involved)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Adding an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=195cfbd011715b500ff643d7fa91843a)

The tricky part is to get the zero records.

For that it can be helpful to create a table which provides all possible combinations:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
        generate_series(1, max(cardinality(myarray))) idx   -- 1
    FROM t
) gs
CROSS JOIN (                                                -- 3
    SELECT DISTINCT                                         -- 2
        unnest(myarray) val
    FROM t
) values
```

1. Create a series from `1` to the max length of an array. This ensures combinations even for different lengths
2. Create a table with all elements which could be appear within any array.
3. `CROSS JOIN` them.

Now you have a reference table. In the next step you can use the `unnest() WITH ORDINALITY` you provided in your own solution. This result can be `LEFT JOIN`ed on the reference table. So you are creating a table with the expected non-zero records and a number of `NULL` records:

```
SELECT
    values.val, gs.idx,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE s.index IS NOT NULL)                   -- 1
FROM (
    SELECT
        generate_series(1, max(cardinality(myarray))) idx
    FROM t
) gs
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        unnest(myarray) val
    FROM t
) values
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM t,
        unnest(myarray) WITH ORDINALITY as a(val, index)
) s ON s.index = gs.idx AND s.val = values.val
GROUP BY values.val, gs.idx
ORDER BY values.val, gs.idx
```

Finally you can group this entire jpoin. Using a `FILTER` clause on `COUNT()` ensures, that only those records are counted, that are not `NULL`, which means: Count only those combinations which really appear in the data. For the `NULL` records, the filter would return `0`.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved like this

```
SELECT a.elem, a.nr, count(a.elem) 
FROM   test t, unnest(t.priorities) WITH ORDINALITY a(elem, nr) GROUP BY a.elem, a.nr;
```

Comment: Note that if you have different numbers of elements, this would not show zero for those that have less elements.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Good point. In my requirements, that case will not occur. But just for learning purposes, how can we achieve that ?

Comment: Your solution does not return the zero records as far as i can see... https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=195cfbd011715b500ff643d7fa91843a

Comment: @S-Man Yes, you are correct. I can work with that but out of curiosity, is there any way to achieve that ?

Comment: See my answer ;)